Calculating supply voltage for a series DC motor
Consider a DC series motor with nominal caracteristics : U=120V, Pa = 3kW, N = 1500 rpm, r = 0.2Ohm inductor resistance, R = 0.3Ohm windings.  Suppose the motor isn't saturated and neglecting all losses beside Joule losses, we study the functioning of this motor assuming that the torque is constant, here is the model of the series DC motor:

I want to find the relation between the speed of rotation and the  power supply U.  Here is what I tried:
\$ U(N) = (r+R)I + E =  (r+R)I + k \phi N \$ I assume that the torque is constant thus \$T = k \phi I = \alpha \in \mathbb{R}\$
Finally, \$ U(N) = 12.5 + \alpha N \$
My main problem is when I tried to find the necessary supply power such that the nominal torque has a rotation speed of N/2 = 750 RPM. When I plug this value in, I get a power supply of U = 66.2254V.
Is this valid logic or am I missing out some logic?

You don't give values for $k$ or $\phi$, nor do you give a value for nominal torque -- those could easily be chosen to give the result you found.  You probably want to edit your question to complete the information.

I dont have the machine between my hand to tell anyone those values, i dont know their values @TimWescott

The quantity symbol $U$ is first defined as a voltage, then redefined as a power. You need to clean up your notation, define your terms, and provide a diagram that models the motor with load. Doing so will assist with finding the answer, @KnowledgeSeeker

If you don't have those values, how did you do your calculation?

I did the following since the absorbed power is 3000Watts: $P_a = U\cdot I = 3000W \iff I = P_a / U = 25 A$ and $E = U - (r+R)I = 107.5V = k \phi \omega $ thus $k \phi = E / \omega = 107.5 V / (1500*2 \pi / 60) = 0.684 $
